# Why does awk concatenate strings from different lines

Tags: linux, bash, awk, grep, printf

Good day.

I'm trying to run a ping6 on IPv6 addresses pulled from /etc/resolv.conf.dnsph.  It seems though, as if awk is stringing the IPv6 addresses onto one line.

```
$ grep ^nameserver /etc/resolv.conf.dnsph |awk '{print $2}'
2001:1890:1001:2224::1
2001:1890:1001:2424::1
$ ping6 $(grep ^nameserver /etc/resolv.conf.dnsph |awk '{print $2}')
ping6: Source routing is deprecated by RFC5095.
Usage: ping6 [-aAbBdDfhLnOqrRUvV] [-c count] [-i interval] [-I interface]
             [-l preload] [-m mark] [-M pmtudisc_option]
             [-N nodeinfo_option] [-p pattern] [-Q tclass] [-s packetsize]
             [-S sndbuf] [-t ttl] [-T timestamp_option] [-w deadline]
             [-W timeout] destination
$ echo $(grep ^nameserver /etc/resolv.conf.dnsph |awk '{print $2}')
2001:1890:1001:2224::1 2001:1890:1001:2424::1
```

Adding "END {printf "\n"}" doesn't make any difference:

```
$ ping6 $(awk '/^nameserver/ {print $2}; END {printf "\n"}' /etc/resolv.conf.dnsph)
ping6: Source routing is deprecated by RFC5095.
Usage: ping6 [-aAbBdDfhLnOqrRUvV] [-c count] [-i interval] [-I interface]
             [-l preload] [-m mark] [-M pmtudisc_option]
             [-N nodeinfo_option] [-p pattern] [-Q tclass] [-s packetsize]
             [-S sndbuf] [-t ttl] [-T timestamp_option] [-w deadline]
             [-W timeout] destination
$ echo $(awk '/^nameserver/ {print $2}; END {printf "\n"}' /etc/resolv.conf.dnsph)
2001:1890:1001:2224::1 2001:1890:1001:2424::1
```

Please advise.

Bjoern

Comment: See [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766) and [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346). Stephen gave you the answer, but you wouldn't have had the question if you had quoted your variable. Try with `echo "$(grep ^nameserver /etc/resolv.conf.dnsph |awk '{print $2}')"` to see.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying terdon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When it’s given multiple addresses, `ping6` interprets them as hops to use to reach the target (the last address). In your case, you need to loop over the output:

```
for ip in $(awk '/^nameserver/ { print $2 }' /etc/resolv.conf.dnsph); do
    ping6 "$ip"
done
```

AWK correctly outputs each IP address on a single line (as can be seen in your first command), but unquoted [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html) causes the newlines to be effectively removed — they act as separators between words.

Comment: Thank you Stephen!  Works like a charm.

I thought I had previously seen someone mention that awk does not print a newline, but can be done by appending `END {print "\n"}`

Comment: @Bjoern: awk `print` does add newline by default; to be exact, it _always_ adds ORS (Output Record Separator) and ORS _defaults_ to newline. `printf` does not add anything (only what you specify in the format string plus argument(s)). Either you misunderstood 'someone' or 'someone' was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The `$(...)` construct is intended to provide command line parameters to commands.
Command line parameters are separated by spaces, not new lines, so the shell "optimizes" the output.
However you can quote `$(...)`, like this:

```bash
> echo $(echo 1;echo 2)
1 2
> echo "$(echo 1;echo 2)"
1
2
```

Still the problem has nothing to do with `awk` concatenating lines (i.e.: it does *not*), but the use of `$(...)`.
Actually `awk` can also do the `grep` job using `awk '/^nameserver/ {print $2}' /etc/resolv.conf.dnsph`, and you can also avoid the shell `for` loop by calling ping from within `awk`:

```bash
awk '/^nameserver/ { system("ping6 " $2); }' /etc/resolv.conf.dnsph
```

Comment: word splitting isn't specific to command substitution though. But also, quoting the command substitution here would give as an argument a single string that contains a newline in the middle, and that's also likely not too useful for `ping6` (or many other tools)